# Dynamic web user control gets refreshed by timer event, so I had recreate them in pageload event, but how to persist focus in a textbox1?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am developing chat application. When user click on online users link, the pop up window (dynamic control) will be shown in an update panel. But due to timer event, after post back dynamically created controls gets deleted from the page.

So in a post back event I will again create them with same id's. But due to this whenever I am trying to type in textbox in an user control. After page refresh, focus from textbox gets diverted. So I have to again and again click on tetxbox to type something in it.

Timer event is used to find whether new message is came for current user in a database or not.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChatWindow.ascx.cs" Inherits="ChatWindow" %>


<div style="width: 211px;border:thick solid #ffa800"> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate> 
          Hi&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>..<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="172px"  Width="186px"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="2000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true">   </asp:Timer>            
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>  </div> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate> 
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="148px"></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" onclick="BtnSend_Click" Text="Send" />   </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

More code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

public partial class ChatWindow : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    int userid, toid;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LN-PUN-D036\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=WCFChat;uid=sa;pwd=imgpoint1*");
    string windowID = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            userid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString());
            this.windowID = this.ID;
            toid =Convert.ToInt32( this.windowID.Substring(5));
            this.Label1.Text = this.ID.ToString();
        }
    }


    protected void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = this.TextBox2.Text;
        var service = new ChatService.Service();

        service.sendmsg(this.TextBox1.Text, userid, toid);
        this.TextBox2.Text += "Me : " + this.TextBox1.Text + "\r\n";
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        //   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Msg,Msg_Id from Message where Msg_Id=(SELECT TOP 1 Msg_Id FROM Message where Msg_To ='" + userid + "' and ReadOrNot='0' ORDER BY Msg_Id DESC) ", con);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Msg,Msg_Id,Msg_From from Message where Msg_To ='" + userid + "' and ReadOrNot='0' and Msg_From = '" + toid + "'", con);

        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LN-PUN-D036\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=WCFChat;uid=sa;pwd=imgpoint1*");
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
        string name = "";
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            hash = (Hashtable)Application["UserHash"];

            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in hash)
            {
                if (de.Key.ToString().Equals(dr[2].ToString().Trim()))
                {
                    name = de.Value.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }

            this.TextBox2.Text += name + " :" + dr[0].ToString() + "\r\n";
            string msgid = dr[1].ToString();
            con2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update Message set ReadOrNot='1' where Msg_Id='" + msgid + "'", con2);
            int i = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con2.Close();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}

 protected void craetecontrols() // this function is in main page in which i am  adding    above user control
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry obj in arr)
        {
            Panel p1 = new Panel();
            p1.ID = "PanelChat" + obj.Key.ToString();
            ChatWindow mycontrol = (ChatWindow)LoadControl("~/ChatWindow.ascx");
            mycontrol.ID = "ChWId" + obj.Key.ToString();
            p1.Controls.Add(mycontrol);
            p1.Style.Add("position", " absolute");
            p1.Style.Add("bottom", "0");
            p1.Style.Add("right", obj.Value.ToString());
            UpdatePanel4.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(p1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more towards design issue. I would suggest you to exclude the typing textbox into a different user control. This `ChatWindow` will only be used to display the chat messages. So when it get refreshed, it wont't interfere with the typing textbox.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have try your solution but it doesnt solved my problem, i think problem is due to recreation of dynamic controls during pageload event.

Comment: i have to further probe into your `Timer1_Tick` event, can you post your coding here? I suspect your are reloading the whole UserControl rather than updating only the chat messages.